# Keyword fires custom CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I have my website witch uses Bootstrap 3 Custom Theme. Im wondering if its possible to add alittle CSS trick. What I would like to do is have a little CSS snippet that will run upon a keyword (tron) type in a users keyboard. Im pretty sure there is a JS keyboard listener for this. But is it possible that when i type TRON on my website it could fire a temp CSS code like so, until page refresh?

```
.btn-primary, .btn-primary.disabled, .btn-primary.disabled:hover, .btn-primary.disabled:active:hover, .btn-primary.disabled:active, .btn-primary.disabled:focus, .btn-primary.disabled:active:focus {
    border-color: #60b6ff;
    color: #60b6ff;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px #0F90FB, 0px 0px 4px #0F90FB;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px #0F90FB, 0px 0px 4px #0F90FB;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px #0F90FB, 0px 0px 4px #0F90FB;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:active:hover {
    border-color: #BCE1FF;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 6px #0F90FB, 0px 0px 12px #0F90FB;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 6px #0F90FB, 0px 0px 12px #0F90FB;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 6px #0F90FB, 0px 0px 12px #0F90FB;
    color: #BCE1FF;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #0F90FB;
}

.btn-primary:active, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active:focus, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary.focus, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary:focus, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary:hover {
    color: #0F90FB;
    border-color: #0F90FB;
    outline: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure I'll use jquery to make things a tad easier.

In my example, I created a CSS classname of 'tron' that is in the CSS sheet for the site. If you wanted more specific elements, you could make them children of the body element with tron as the class.  In my example all that does is set the background of the body to blue, but again you can do whatever you like w/ the CSS rules.

Given that, all you need to do is listen for the 'keyup' event, and anytime four letters spelling 'tron' are entered in sequence, you change the body class to 'tron'.  I have it so it'll keep firing after tron is set (so the next four letters typed will reset it), but if that's not the behavior you want this should give you the general idea.

Here's the JS, and I gave a link to the full plunker:

```
$(function(){
  var tron = '';
  $('body').on('keyup', function(e){
    tron += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    if(tron.length == 4){
      if(tron === 'TRON'){
        $('body').addClass('tron');

      }else{
        if($('body').hasClass('tron')){
          $('body').removeClass('tron');
        }
        tron = '';
      }
    }
  })
})
```

The plunkr is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/KAVRlJo7C7Bao1LBIQDz

Comment: nice example, except it only works iff you type 'tron' anything before and it's broken

Comment: a better way would be to use any number of ways in JS to check a substring and not to set `tron = ''` or better yet just throw out your else because it'll never matter, it'll try to remove a class that was never added in the first place.

Comment: Fair point. I was going for clearing the class in the case that you typed four letters that didn't spell tron.  Checking for the class first is another way to do that, since it only runs every 4 letters.

Comment: thanks for the code snippet but I need something like below where it will load a separate CSS file upon typing tron anywhere on site.....then will disappear upon page refresh

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example just make a css sheet with your new css and replace `link.href = 'newcss.css'`with the link to your style sheet.

```
var tronstr = ''
  function tron(e){
    switch (e.key) {
      case "t":
        if(tronstr.length == 0){
          tronstr = 't'
        }
        break;
      case "r":
        if(tronstr.length == 1){
          tronstr = 'tr'
        }else{
          tronstr = ''
        }
        break;
      case "o":
        if(tronstr.length == 2){
          tronstr = 'tro'
        }else{
          tronstr = ''
        }
        break;
      case "n":
        if(tronstr.length == 3){
          tronstr = 'tron'
        }else{
          tronstr = ''
        }
        break;
      default:
        tronstr = ''
    }
    if(tronstr == 'tron'){
      var head = document.head, link = document.createElement('link')
      link.type = 'text/css'
      link.rel = 'stylesheet'
      link.href = 'newcss.css'
      head.appendChild(link)

    }
    console.log(tronstr);
  }
```

Comment: i tried this but it doesnt work......inserted code into head and change css location.

Comment: opps forgot to add the key listener to the body. Heres a new plunkr that actually works http://plnkr.co/edit/WIjutkFVEnNA4VT3IETz?p=preview. Sorry about that

Comment: worked like a charm thanks....seems to not work with safari though...chrome is good though.